# deck gl Icon cluster layer view all tooltip on load

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl, deck.gl, supercluster

Hello everyone Hope you all doing well.

I am implementing map using deck.gl icon Layer, have to develop a view where all tooltip's can be shown by default. I am not able to find how to get all cluster and layer data segregated by default to show on load. Deck.gl default feature is to get data on hover/click on the cluster or layer but not on load.

Can anyone help getting it done. Thanks in advance

Link to the example: https://deck.gl/examples/icon-layer